# Can I create an implicit Lifetime scope within a factory?

Tags: autofac

Does Autofac support implicit lifetime scopes for the use of a factory? For example, I would like to be able to do the following

```
public class Session : IDisposable
{
    public Session(A a, B b, C c)
    {
        ...
    }
} 

...

using (var session = _sessionFactory())
{
    ...
}
```

and then upon each call to the _sessionFactory have Autofac automatically create a nested lifetime scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Let the factory return `Owned<Session>`. [Owned instances](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OwnedInstances) indicates that the calling code is responsible for disposing the service. Actually, if you resolve a `Func<Owned<Session>>` from the container, Autofac will give you an automatic factory that produces such instances.

Comment: Hi Peter, what I also want though is that the call to my factory also implicitly calls a BeginLifetimeScope which is then tracked with the Disposing of my factory. That way I don't have to inject the ILifetimeScope into my class itself.

Comment: @cosullivan - not sure if I mis-understand something here, the whole point with `Owned<>` is that it is indeed its own lifetime scope. When you resolve some `Owned<>` instance from the container, Autofac will create a new lifetime scope for you. Disposing the `Owned<Session>` instance will also dispose the `Session` instance, and any `IDisposable` dependencies of `Session`. So yes, if you have a factory that resolves `Owned<>`, Autofac will handle scoping for you.