# Implicit scope on resolve without using Autofac namespace

Tags: c#, autofac

I am trying to figure out how to get a new lifetime scope each time I resolve an instance from the container. I would like to do this without the depending component needing to know about Autofac.

I'm creating a .NET Core server application (console app) which has a "master server" (`IMasterServer`) component and zero or more "session server" (`ISessionServer`) components. Both the master and the session servers have their own `IMessageBroker` dependency. The master server will create a new session server whenever it gets a message from the message broker.

The catch is that each session server instance needs its own `IMessageBroker`, and I don't think I can use `InstancePerDependency()` because other sub-components of `ISessionServer` will also need to access the `IMessageBroker` so the message broker needs to be single instance within the scope of a session. So my thinking is that when the master server spawns a new session, it should do so within a new lifetimescope, and I can register the `IMessageBroker` dependency using `InstancePerLifetimeScope()`.

So, the question is, how can I inject an `ISessionServer` factory into `IMasterServer` such that each time that factory is called, a new lifetime scope is created for the resulting `ISessionServer` instance? And how can this be done such that none of the components need to know about Autofac?

These two SO questions both suggest using the `Owned<T>` relationship:

[Can I create an implicit Lifetime scope within a factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544952/can-i-create-an-implicit-lifetime-scope-within-a-factory)

[Is it possible to create a new scope whenever a component is resolved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155170/is-it-possible-to-create-a-new-scope-whenever-a-component-is-resolved/39173964#39173964)

However, unless I'm missing something, that means that the component into which the dependency will be injected (`IMasterServer` in my case) needs to know about Autofac, because its ctor signature must include the `Owned<T>` type.

What I have so far:

```
using Autofac.Features.OwnedInstances;

class MasterServer : IMasterServer
{
    private IMessageBroker mMessageBroker;
    private Func<Owned<ISessionServer>> mSessionServerFactory;

    public Master(
        Func<string, IServerMessageBroker> messageBrokerFactory,
        Func<Owned<ISessionServer>> sessionServerFactory
    )
    {
        mMessageBroker = messageBrokerFactory("master");
        mSessionServerFactory = sessionServerFactory;
    }
}


class SessionServer : ISessionServer
{
    private IMessageBroker mMessageBroker;
    private string mId;

    public SessionServer(
        Func<string, IMessageBroker> messageBrokerFactory
    )
    {
        mId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        mMessageBroker = messageBrokerFactory(mId);
    }
}
```

You can see that the MasterServer concrete class needs to use the `Autofac.Features.OwnedInstances` namespace in order to define the session factory using the `Owned<T>` relationship type.

How can I use Autofac to create a new lifetime scope each time `ISessionServer` is resolved through the factory injected into the `MasterServer`, without the components needing to know anything about the specific DI container in use?

Answer (score 0):

I always felt that letting Autofac-specific code slip onto factory classes is the less of two evils.
So, if I was in you, I would just use the `Owned<T>` class, call it a day and move on. It's an excellent solution and keeps all the disposing of every component automagical as always with Autofac.

Just remember to call `Dispose` or your owned `SessionServer` when needed, or you will leak resources.

AFAICT the Autofac approach doesn't let you write 100% DI free code. So you need to reference it, someway, somewhere.

A single reference to include `Owned<T>` seems a pretty acceptable trade off.

Let me point out a problem in your design (or in the part you included): there is no simple way to link a ISessionServer into a disposable scope.

E.g: you expose a factory class, and then the SessionServer is out on his own.
Managing scopes in this way becomes hard.

A cleaner approach is to use a Disposable into a using statement:

```
using (var sessionServer = sessionFactory.GetServer())
{
    // do something with sessionServer.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. As I continue to develop this app, I'm seeing that there are other places where implementing valuable Autofac features will result in more of my components needing to know about Autofac. I suppose I should just accept it, as you suggest.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion to wrap the `SessionServer` in a using block, I don't think I can do that because the `MasterServer` needs to hang onto a collection of `SessionServer` instances. It will dispose of them when it is Disposed.

Comment: I would suggest you to keep Autofac usage on specific spots. As an example, you could make a class `SessionServerHandle` implementing a `getSessionServer()` method, and responsible for creation of a specific Autofac scope, instantiation and disposal of the `SessionServer` instance. In short, a class responsible for managing the unit of work.

Comment: My rule of thumb is that implementation classes should be Autofac free. Special classes like Factories or so are the one place I let DI code slip into the implementation.